# Backbone js Asp.net Mvc AsyncController

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, backbone.js

We're trying to get backbone to work with an async controller but the data seems to be saving with odd IDs - should backbone be able to work with AsyncController out of the box or is there something I need to set to tell it it's dealing with an async action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not tried backbone with an async controller but as far as I know it should work.  2 things worth checking:

1) You mentioned "odd IDs" -- are you returning the id that was generated on the server back to the client so the backbone models can be updated?  if so, be sure that you're passing back `id` which is case-sensitive.  (this can be changed if necessary using the `idAttribute` property of your models)

2) are your controller methods decorated with the right post verbs?  (this is just a long shot)

If neither of these help, post some code and I'll take a look.

Comment: I second that backbone should have no problem with async controller. It should pretty much be agnostic to the server-side technology.